# Magento is Stripping all EXIF Data When Uploaded

Tags: php, magento, seo, exif

Because this shop is an eCommerce it helps a lot to have picture with EXIF data, but for some reason when the images with EXIF data is uploaded magento seems to strip all of that info from the image and only show the bare image in the front end.!

can anyone tell me why this is happening and how we can avoid it?

Cheer!

Comment: Same problem on Magento2. A decade after your initial post :(

Answer (score 2):

It's a side effect of using the GD2 library for resizing.

`lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/GD2.php`

See if there's a module out there that uses ImageMagick if you want to preserve EXIF

[Quote from PHP website on using GD:](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

> When developing code to resize images, it is best not to use GD.  When
>   using the current GD methodologies, you are reading content from an
>   image and manipulating it.  By then writing that content to a brand
>   new file, you are losing the EXIF data.
>
> For purposes when you want to retain EXIF data, it is recommended that
>   you compile in and use the PECL Imagemagick extension.  It has great
>   resizing methods built right in and the EXIF data is retained.

ImageMagick isn't used because of issues with server loading.